# Multiple logistic regression comparing multiple categorical predictors and multiple binary outcomes

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, binary-data, categorical-data

Say I have a dataframe `data`:

```
Name      V1      V2      V3
Name 1    0       1       1
Name 1    0       0       1
Name 1    1       1       1
Name 2    1       0       0
Name 2    0       0       1
Name 2    1       1       0
Name 3    1       0       0
Name 3    1       0       1
Name 3    1       1       0
```

The factors `Name 1`, `Name 2`, and `Name 3` are categorical variables which predict the binary outcomes listed in `V1:V3`.

I want to perform an ANOVA or multiple logistic regression which compares each of the factors in `data$name` in terms of the distribution of binary outcomes shown in `V1:V3`, but am not sure about how to go about it / how to alter my dataframe to appropriately perform the analysis. Have tried both `Anova()` and `glm(family=binomial(link="logit")` on individual factors from `data$Name`, but that doesn't quite produce the comparison I am looking for. The type of analysis I want to perform would tell me if `Name 1` is more likely to have a certain outcome for one or all of the response variables `V1:V3` compared to `Name 2` and/or `Name 3`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn´t sound like ANOVA would be appropriate in this case, but logistic regression should be fine. You can do logistic regression for *each* of the outcome variables:

```
data$Name <- as.factor(data$Name)
yourmodel <- glm(V1 ~ Name, data=data, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Or another option (as suggested in comments):

```
yourmodel <- glm(Name ~V1 + V2 +V3, data=data, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

...in each case you can get the model residuals, coefficents etc by:

```
summary(yourmodel)
```

...from which you can extract the odds ratios.

Comment: I think the poster of the question is looking for: `yourmodel <- glm(Name ~ V1 + V2 +V3, data=data, family=binomial(link="logit"))`. But his question is somewaht unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. In the event that one of the factors in data$Name contains only 0's for a given outcome variable, I've noticed that the data$Name variable is not shown in the summary(glmmodel) output. Is there a way to include such variables in the output?

Comment: @soosus:  Theoretically all 0´s can cause a problem for calculations. Have you tried to feed to `glm` individually?

Comment: Actually now I'm realizing that one of the factors isn't being reported for any of the glm() calls I'm running regardless of 0's. The factor is still in dataframe being used. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: And does this occur also if you try the first method?

Comment: Yes. It appears to be dependent on the alphabetic order of the factors. I've changed the factor string names to change their alphabetic order, and always the first factor gets dropped (and seems to be used as the intercept?) which drastically changes the results depending on which factor occupies the "first in the alphabet" position.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that glm() is using the first factor as reference. I will just run the summaries on each possible combination of factors.